# getting Key from collection of KeyValuePairs

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to finally get my head around LINQ, but am struggling with the following...

I have a collection of KeyValuePairs, defined as follows:

```
IList<KeyValuePair<int, MyCustomType>>
```

where the int Key of the KeyValuePair is allowed to repeat in the collection.

How do I get a collection (array, IList - I don't care) of unique keys from this collection?

I know I need to use Distinct but I'm struggling with the KeyValuePair in my collection and getting at the Key...

Comment: I can recommend http://powercollections.codeplex.com/ which have a multi-dictionary where you can have multiple values for each key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just:

```
var keys = pairs.Select(x => x.Key)
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
```

Of course if the collection of pairs originally came from a dictionary, you can remove the `Distinct()` call as they'll already be distinct.

Answer (score 3):

```
list.Select(pair => pair.Key)
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for that, worked a treat.  It was what to pass through the lambda was throwing me.